# Not able to remove just the last element from the linked list! (All other elements with the particular value are removed)

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to remove nodes from a linkedlist that have a particular value , i am to remove all nodes except the last one,for the given input. I have also added the 'elif' case especially to remove that last node, but don't realise why it's not working. I am fairly new to programming and data structures, and not able to pinpoint the mistake. Please help :)

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
    self.value = value
    self.next_node = next_node

  def get_value(self):
    return self.value

  def get_next_node(self):
    return self.next_node

  def set_next_node(self, next_node):
    self.next_node = next_node

class LinkedList:
  def __init__(self, value=None):
    self.head_node = Node(value)

  def get_head_node(self):
    return self.head_node

  def new_beginning(self, new_value):
    new_node = Node(new_value)
    new_node.set_next_node(self.head_node)
    self.head_node = new_node

  def stringify_list(self):
    string_list = ""
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    while current_node:
      if current_node.get_value() != None:
        string_list += str(current_node.get_value()) + "\n"
      current_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    return string_list

  def remove_node(self, value_to_remove):
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    if current_node.get_value() == value_to_remove:
      self.head_node = current_node.get_next_node()
    else:
      while current_node:
        next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
        if next_node.get_value() == value_to_remove:
          current_node.set_next_node(next_node.get_next_node())
          current_node = None
        else:
          current_node = next_node

  def remove_all_nodes(self,remove_value):
    current_node = self.get_head_node()
    while current_node:
      if current_node ==self.get_head_node() and current_node.value== remove_value:
        self.head_node = current_node.get_next_node()
        current_node = self.get_head_node()
      else:
        next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
        if next_node!= None and next_node.value == remove_value:
          prev_node = current_node
          current_node.set_next_node(next_node.get_next_node())

          current_node = next_node.get_next_node()
        elif (next_node == None) and (current_node.value == remove_value):
          #current_node = None
          prev_node.set_next_node(None)
        else:
          prev_node = current_node
          current_node = next_node


link_list = LinkedList(13)
link_list.new_beginning(13)
link_list.new_beginning(14)
link_list.new_beginning(15)
link_list.new_beginning(100)
link_list.new_beginning(13)
link_list.new_beginning(133)
link_list.new_beginning(13)
link_list.new_beginning(199)
link_list.new_beginning(13)
link_list.new_beginning(13)

print(link_list.stringify_list())
#print(len(link_list))

link_list.remove_all_nodes(13)

print(link_list.stringify_list())
```

[The last 13 is still not getting removed, please suggest changes so that i am able to remove that too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Tmb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `remove_node` function:

```py
elif (next_node == None) and (current_node.value == remove_value):
          current_node = None
```

In this part - you did not change the list itself, you change the variable `current_node` and put `None` into it. What you really want to do is the change `next_node` attribute of the previous node to be `None`.

There are two major ways to do that:

1. When you iterate inside the function you can hold a second variable, previous_node. When you want to delete a node, you change previous_node (the node) next_node (attribute) to skip one. If it is the last one, you change his next_node to none.
2. make it a double connected list, where every node also hold his previous node. It is more easy to iterate that way. Essentially it is the same logic, you must go to previous node and change his next node to none. Just easier then hold a second variable.

**Edit:** After you edited your code and implement previous_node, you still have one problem in your code. Here is a fixed code:

```py
    def remove_all_nodes(self,remove_value):
        current_node = self.get_head_node()
        while current_node:
            if current_node == self.get_head_node() and current_node.value == remove_value:
                self.head_node = current_node.get_next_node()
                current_node = self.get_head_node()
            else:
                next_node = current_node.get_next_node()
                prev_node = current_node
                if next_node != None and next_node.value == remove_value:
                    current_node.set_next_node(next_node.get_next_node())
                elif (next_node == None) and (current_node.value == remove_value):
                    prev_node.set_next_node(None)
                    current_node = None
                else:
                    current_node = next_node
```

There are few changes from your code (the edited version):

1. prev_node declaration should be outside of the if statement, because you want to use it value inside some cases
2. Removed the line `current_node = next_node.get_next_node()` from the first statement. Your currently logic is: look one node ahead, remove it if needed and advance current node. But what happens when you have 2 values (of 13 for example) in row? you take out the first and then advances the node, so you currently on the second. You can not remove it since you always remove one node ahead. The problem here was not "last element" but "2 elements in a row". After I remove this line: after a node removed from the list, it just make an iteration again on current node. That's why it will keep removing next node and advance it only when it is "safe" to advance.

Now the output is as expected

Comment: Hey, i made the changes according to the 1st way as i am not comfortable with doubly linked list for now and was trying to implement it by singly linked list, it is getting stuck in some kind of infinite loop, can you tell me the error?

Comment: Thanks @Roim , i was totally ignoring this 'The problem here was not "last element" but "2 elements in a row" ', i get it now :)